# indexOf method asking for a char that appears multiple times?

Tags: java, string, indexof

```
 String str = "Aardvark";
 str.indexOf('a');
```

I was wondering what index str would return if it asked for a certain character and the string contained multiple of it. For example, aardvark: would the method return index 0, for the first instance it saw the char? There are 3 'a' chars in the word, so which would it return?

One additional question (couldn't fit it in the original question)
What is the difference between

```
 str.indexOf('a');
```

and

```
 str.indexOf("a");
```

I know the first is a char and the second is a String, but if str = "Aardvark", wouldn't the second statement return -1 or some sort of error, because "a" refers to a single-character String, not one char of a string?

I'm very sorry if this was unclear, I couldn't really think of a better way to pose my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it out and then see what the results are? Or you could read the documentation for the indexOf method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Answer (score 1):

1. `indexOf()` will return the index of the first occurrence of the string/char
2. like you say, one looks for a char and the other on a sub string. "a" will be found, as "a" is a substring of "Aardvark"

Answer (score 1):

It would print the first occurence..

To get the second occurence you
would have to 
fill in

```
indexOf(char c, int lookafterfirstindex);
```

indexOf can also take those two parameters instead of just the char.

Link to API Doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
String text = "abcd_a";

    System.out.println("Index of a: "+ text.indexOf('a'));  // Index of a: 0
    System.out.println("Index of a: "+ text.indexOf("a"));  // Index of a: 0
    System.out.println("Index of b: "+ text.indexOf('b'));  // Index of b: 1
    System.out.println("Index of c: "+ text.indexOf('c'));  // Index of c: 2
    System.out.println("Index of z: "+ text.indexOf('z'));  // Index of z: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

***simple index of***:
indexOf(char/string) will always return the first index of the occurrence.

***from index***:
There is also indexOf(char/string, int fromIndex) - which will search from a given position in your string.

***last index***:
There is a lastIndexOf(char/string) - which will search last occurrence.

Regarding the char vs String, I would use char if I only need one char index lookup. **The char will peform much faster than the String** index-lookup-methods!!!

[Java String Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)